# Wix per-user installer cannot write to Program Files

Tags: .net, wix, installation, wix3.8

I am using Wix 3.9.1208.

I have an installer created earlier with Install Shield Limited Edition that installed as a per user package. I now need to upgrade the program using Wix as I need the additional functionality Wix provides.

The issue I am having is when I use Wix as the installer and I have the InstallScope attribute set to per-user I get an error message that says “the installer has insufficient privileges to access this directory” and the message is pointing to the Program Files/My Application directory.

I get this issue whether the UAC dialog appears or not. I’ve tested by switching to a per-machine install (InstallScope=perMachine) and it works as expected. However my installer must be per-user at it is an upgrade and must match the installed scope of the previous installation.

This has always worked with "Setup and Deployment" and InstallShield so I don't know why Wix can't handle writing to Program Files during a per-user install?

Here is my package element:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="300" 
         Compressed="yes" 
         InstallScope="perUser"
         InstallPrivileges="elevated" 
         Keywords="some keywords" 
         Platform="x64" 
         Manufacturer="my manufacturer"
         Comments="some comment" />
```

Is there anyway around this so I can trick or force Wix to install to Program Files for a per-user install?

Answer (score 0):

It's the intended behavior:

Rob Mensching says:

> You have to be elevated to install to ProgramFiles. Your per-user MSI never should have been able to install to ProgramFiles unless you always launched it from an elevated process.
>   s. [sourceforge mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/34095636/)